# Regular expression - extract mailto: mail address

Tags: regex

example: mailto:info@info.com?subjectsomething
         or mailto:info@info.com

I would like to get only the email address with no subject (if any)

This expression is not enought and I can't make it work:

```
mailto:(.*)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this on a text line by itself or within other text (like on an HTML page)? Also helps to know language you are looking to do the search in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Regular Expression:

```
mailto:([^\?]*)
```

Comment: This is matching a string that literally starts with "mailto:" but discards that information because it's not inside the parentheses. Then it matches 0 or more characters until it encounters the `?` character, and returns the matched characters as a capture group.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save matched characters in a capture group:

```
mailto:([^?]+)
```

Now you have your address in $1 (or in other variable; depends on language).

If it is possible that after email address goes something else, you must specify the delimiters. For example, if it is space:

```
mailto:([^?\S]+)[\s?]
```

You can also use non-greedy r.e.:

```
mailto:(.+?)[\s?]
```

That means "stop as soon as you'll meet `\s` (space) or `?`

Answer (score 0):

This will look for the matching string within a word boundary.  You would need to get the value of the email from the first parenthesized sub-pattern using your language of choice (typically the reference to it would be $1). The second sub-pattern would capture the subject (with ? at the beginning).

```
\bmailto:(.*)(\?.*)?\b
```